# how to place page number in reportviewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I inserted a line into the header report as long as the Tablix1 and in the footer I insert a PageNumber

`"Page nr.: " & Globals!PageNumber & " - " & Globals!ExecutionTime`

right-aligned to Tablix1.
When I view the report the Tablix1 stretches to the right but the line remains stump and in the footer the PageNumber is centered, while I would like it to the right. How can I intervene by code?
Thank you for any helpful advice

Comment: Would llike to solve this, if you elaborate your question little bit more. It will be very good if you can provide screenshots.